# PHP Header exists but cannot retrieve

Tags: php, json, apache, slim

I am using this method to make apache header request work in nginx.

```
if (!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) { 
    function apache_request_headers() { 
        foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) { 
            if (substr($key,0,5)=="HTTP_") { 
                $key=str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",substr($key,5))))); 
                $out[$key]=$value; 
            }else{ 
                $out[$key]=$value; 
            } 
        } 
        return $out; 
    } 
}
```

I retrieve the header like so `$headers = apache_request_headers();` and use an array to hold json.

```
$response=array()
$response["error"] = true;
$response["message"] = $headers;
```

The code below is what is inside of the $response array variable:

```
{
error: true
message: {
CONTENT_LENGTH: "13"
CONTENT_TYPE: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/home4/admin/public_html"
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
Accept: "*/*"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
Accept-Language: "en-US,en;q=0.8"
Connection: "close"
Cookie: "_ga=GA1.2.1266385826.1428275832"
Host: "mysite.com"
Origin: "chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo"
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36"
X-Apikey: "bca0de3e7c10cb6623ef00021caf9450"
X-Http-Proto: "HTTP/1.1"
X-Log-7528: "107.147.160.193"
X-Real-Ip: "107.147.160.193"
PATH: "/bin:/usr/bin"
PHPRC: "/home4/admin"
QUERY_STRING: ""
REDIRECT_STATUS: "200"
REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID: "VVlk5sD@@rgAACwVT0AAAACM"
REDIRECT_URL: "/rmapp/v1/tasks"
REMOTE_ADDR: "107.147.160.193"
REMOTE_PORT: "31527"
REQUEST_METHOD: "POST"
REQUEST_URI: "/rmapp/v1/tasks"
SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/home4/admin/public_html/rmapp/v1/index.php"
SCRIPT_NAME: "/rmapp/v1/index.php"
SERVER_ADDR: "192.185.226.161"
SERVER_ADMIN: "webmaster@mysite.com"
SERVER_NAME: "mysite.com"
SERVER_PORT: "80"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
SERVER_SIGNATURE: "<address>Apache Server at mysite.com Port 80</address> "
SERVER_SOFTWARE: "Apache"
UNIQUE_ID: "VVlk5sD@@rgAACwVT0AAAACM"
PHP_SELF: "/rmapp/v1/index.php"
REQUEST_TIME: 1431921894
argv: [0]
argc: 0
}-
}
```

My problem is, I need to grab X-ApiKey from $header, but using `$api_key = $headers['X-ApiKey'];` returns nothing, but as you can see, `X-ApiKey` exists in `$header`. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong variable name.  Variable names are case-sensitive.

The response returns the following (small k in Apikey):
`X-Apikey: "bca0de3e7c10cb6623ef00021caf9450"`

while you are using capital k `$api_key = $headers['X-ApiKey'];`

Try the following:
`$api_key = $headers['X-Apikey'];`

Comment: This is the correct answer. The array key used have different case.

Answer (score 1):

`$response["message"]` is a `string`. First try to `explode` it and then access it -

```
$temp = explode('X-Apikey:', $response['message']);
$temp1 = explode('X-Http-Proto:', $temp[1]);
var_dump(trim(str_replace('"', '', $temp1[0])));
```

**Output**

```
string(32) "bca0de3e7c10cb6623ef00021caf9450"
```

Comment: Have you even read the question carefully ?? The OP is trying to get value from `$headers['X-ApiKey'];` and not from `$response`

Comment: @Letmesee Have you?? `$response["message"] = $headers;`

Comment: @sgtBOSE Read the first line after the sample code which says ... `$api_key = $headers['X-ApiKey']; returns nothing`

Comment: I cant answer doesn't mean I will give the wrong one :)

Comment: @Letmesee Thats exactly what OP is doing wrong. `$headers` is a string and not an array. This answer basically tells how to extract `'X-ApiKey'` from that string `$response['message']` (which is equal to `$headers`).

Comment: @Ulver `I retrieve the header like so $headers = apache_request_headers(); and use an array to hold json.` As far as I can see `apache_request_headers()` returns array not json string

Comment: @Letmesee Gotcha! Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Letmesee Ask the OP to add the output of `$headers` only.